# Printing value of a pointer to a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to wrap my head around "pointer to a pointer". And I tried some experiments and I got stuck here for a while:

```
int array[5] = {4 , 5 ,6 ,7 ,8};
int *p = array;
int **pp = &p;
for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i ++)
{
    printf("\nprinting\n");
    printf("Source: %d\n", array[i]);
    printf("Output by pointer: %d, %d\n", p[i], *(p + i));
    printf("Output by pointer to a pointer: %d, %d\n", *pp[i], **(pp + i) );
}
```

And I got this as output:

```
printing
Source: 4
Output by pointer: 4, 4
Output by pointer to a pointer: 4, 4

printing
Source: 5
Output by pointer: 5, 5
```

I don't understand why after 1 loop, the program stop at the 2nd loop- line 9. Did I misunderstand anything basic knowledge or something else.
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the last `printf` to:

```
printf("Output by pointer to a pointer: %d, %d\n", (*pp)[i], *(*pp + i) );
```

You're basically using `*pp` in place of `p`, but the `*` operator doesn't group as tightly as `[]` so you need to use parentheses in the first form.  In the second form, you need to dereference `pp` before adding `i`, after which the result is dereferenced.

Comment: Thank you. This reply is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

For starters it is unclear why there is used the magic number 4 in the loop instead of the number 5 that is the number of elements in the array

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i ++)
                 ^^^^^
```

The pointer `pp` does not point to first element of an array. It points to a single object

```
int **pp = &p;
```

So these expressions

```
*pp[i]  (that is equivalent to *(pp[i] )
```

and

```
**(pp + i)
```

does not make sense.

An expression using the pointer `p` can be written using the pointer `pp` like `*pp`.

So these correct expressions

```
p[i]
```

and

```
*(p + i)
```

can be written using the pointer `pp` the following way (just substitute `p` for `*pp` taking into account operation precedences)

```
( *pp )[i]
```

and

```
*( *pp + i )
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand more by your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You acesses to pointer thru pointer-to-pointers are wrong:
you must access the pointee as the array:

```
int array[5] = {4 , 5 ,6 ,7 ,8};
int *p = array;
int **pp = &p;
for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i ++)
{
    printf("\nprinting\n");
    printf("Source: %d\n", array[i]);
    printf("Output by pointer: %d, %d\n", p[i], *(p + i));
    printf("Output by pointer to a pointer: %d, %d\n", (*pp)[i], *(*pp + i) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong

```
printf("Output by pointer to a pointer: %d, %d\n", *pp[i], **(pp + i) );
```

You need to change it to

```
printf("Output by pointer to a pointer: %d, %d\n", (*pp)[i], *(*pp + i) );
```

so that you dereference the double pointer before using it as a normal pointer.

You can think of it like this:

> p is the same as (*pp)

In other words - in a valid expression that uses `p` you are allowed to substitute `p` with `(*pp)`. That is

```
p[i]     --> (*p)[i]
*(p + i) --> *((*pp) + i) --> *(*pp + i)
```

Notice that the parenthesis is important. The parenthesis can be removed in the second example but not in the first as `[]` has higher precedence than `*`.

Doing `pp + i` generates a pointer that doesn't point to any valid object. So when you dereference it using `**(pp + i)` you do an illegal access an your program crashes.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination :).